# noqa isort in module imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, isort

I'm struggling with isort library which is sorting imports in my project.

To avoid circular dependencies, I need to import packages in following order:

```py
from foo import *
from bar import *
from eggs import *
from spam import *
```

But instead of that it sort them alphabetically as you may expect.

```py
from bar import *
from eggs import *
from foo import *
from spam import *
```

I tried to use `noqa` with some codes for import lines and for whole file, but it didn't help.

How to ignore/noqa orderign for that import?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `isort:skip` is what you are looking. Here are few more [examples and options of how to use it](https://github.com/PyCQA/isort#skip-processing-of-imports-outside-of-configuration):

```py
from foo import *  # isort:skip
from bar import *
from eggs import *
from spam import *
```